# c++: Passing const int to template function

Tags: c++, templates, constants

I am using the rapidxml lib.
It defines a function to parse files in this way:

```
template<int Flags>
void parse(Ch *text)
```

The lib provides `const int` flags for example:

```
const int parse_declaration_node = 0x20;
```

So I created a pointer to a static int in my class:

```
const int * parser_mode;
```

And in the class constructor I assigned it its value:

```
parser_mode = &rapidxml::parse_declaration_node;
```

Then when I try to use this `const int *` as template argument to the parse function:

```
tree->parse<parser_mode>(file->data());
```

I get this error message:

> error: ‘GpxSectionData::parser_mode’ cannot appear in a
>   constant-expression

This rest of the statement seems correct since:

```
tree->parse<0>(file->data());
```

doesn't produce compilation error...

Could you please tell me what I am missing here?
Thank you!

---

Thanks to the explanations below I will probably define it out of the class:
So I think this is:

```
class Myclass {
static const int parser_mode;
[...]
}
static const int Myclass::parser_mode = rapidxml::parse_declaration_node;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`template<int Flags> void parse(Ch *text)` ... `const int * parser_mode;`

Your template takes an `int` as a template parameter, but you are passing it an `int*`. The types `int` and `int*` are not the same.

Try `tree->parse<rapidxml::parse_declaration_node>(file->data());`

Comment: Also note that even `*parser_mode` is not a compile-time constant expression, so he must use the full name (as you demonstrate) or instantiate `static const int parser_mode = rapidxml::parse_declaration_node;` outside of the constructor

Comment: Okay. Did I correctly understood the issue if I say that the templates arguments need to be resolved during compilation. So even if my `parser_mode` points to a `const int`, since the pointer itself will be defined during runtime, the object cannot be build? So even if I use a `const int * const parser_mode`, this will fail during compilation?

Comment: @Rob: BTW, I also realized that trying with `parsermode` instead of `*parser_mode` was stupid. The error message with the `*` was even more confusing, and it confused me. Pointers need a little practice when you are learning c++! Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use variable for value of template parameter.

Instead you can add Flags template parameter to your class

```
template<int Flags>
class CClass {
    //...
};
```

And set Flags parameter for class instance

```
CClass<rapidxml::parse_declaration_node> obj;
```

Comment: Thank you, good to know this too. Even if in my case it may be not so easy to use (but you can't know!). Indeed I may need to add other const variables inside my class over time.